# regex problem - select results by id

Tags: regex

Here's my regex problem: How can I select all results with a certain ID, e.g.  "...ID=99" but excluding the results countinuing with an additional number like ID="990" or "ID=9923".
However if the string countinues with another non-number character ("&"), e.g. "...ID=99&PARAM=9290" it also should be included.

I am totally confused turning this into a regex selection. I would appreciate any idea on this very much!

(by the way if you are really into regex. how did you learn it? any recommended resources, books, tutorials?)

Note: I use this to filter my search results in google analytics as you can actually use regex in the "Filter Page" form. Maybe this is useful information to you.

Comment: are we talking about URL parameters?

Comment: @Dave: what string function would you use to match "ID=99" as long as it's not followed by another digit?  Looks like a job for regex to me.

Comment: @Alan: You're right; I wasn't thinking clearly. Thanks for the correction. Removing unhelpful comment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use \b, word boundary, i.e.

ID=99\b

For books [Regular Expression Recipes: A Problem-Solution Approach](http://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/tg/detail/-/159059441X/ref=ase_penguintelecomin/102-8353601-4848123?v=glance&s=books) is a good one.

Answer (score 1):

Answering the second part of your question:

As far as books are concerned, [Regular Expression Cookbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596520689) by O'Reilly is fantastic. The first few chapters pretty much cover all the basics, and then some. The rest of the book is concrete examples.

Answer (score 1):

```
ID=99(?!\d)
```

`(?!\d)` is a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html); it asserts that **either** the next character is not a digit **or** there is no next character.  You didn't say what regex flavor you're using, but most of the so-called Perl-compatible flavors support lookaheads.

As for learning resources, the tutorial at [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) is a great place to start.  For advanced study, the Goyvaerts-Levithan book recommended by others is excellent, but [Mastering Regular Expressions](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596528124) is still the best.  Get both if you can afford them; you won't regret it.

EDIT: To be on the safe side, you might want to use `\bID=99(?!\d)` to avoid matching something like `FOO_ID=99`.

Answer (score 0):

This will match ID=99 and ID=99 followed by a single non-digit char.

```
ID=99(:?\D)?
```

If 99 was just an example and you want to match any two digits, you can use:

```
ID=\d{2}(:?\D)?
```

Comment: Won't work, even if you fix the syntax. `(?:\D)?` optionally matches a non-digit, but it doesn't *prevent* a match if the next character **is** a digit (which is what the OP wants).